# Esconder certa quantidade de itens

Tags: jquery

Supondo que eu tenha 10 `div class="code"` no meu documento! Como faço para adicionar um botão, para que ao carregar a pagina apenas 5 desses itens fique a mostra, e os outros 5 fiquem escondidos, e após clicar no botão esses outros 5 fique também a mostra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma usando a função toggle do jQuery e o seletor lt(n) para selecionar os primeiros 5 itens:

```js
$(function() {

  var codes = $('.code');
  var first5 = $('.code:lt(5)');
  
  codes.toggle();
  first5.toggle();

  $('#btn-show-hide').click(function() {
  
    codes.toggle();
    first5.toggle();
  
  });

});
```

```css
.code {
  
  min-height: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<input type="button" id="btn-show-hide" value="Mostrar / Esconder">
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery

```
$(".divIDClass").hide();
```

javascrpt

```
document.getElementByClass("divIDClass").style.display = 'none';
```

ambos selecionados por classe

Comment: Se usares `getElementByClass` isso vai dar uma coleção. Tens de usar `[0]` para selecionar só um elemento e poderes usar o `.style`